# cairo-dock starts up at the bottom-right

Tags: startup, cairo-dock

When i turn on my computer (ubuntu 13.10) the cairo-dock starts up automatically but it starts up at the bottom-right as you can see in the photo.
I solve the problem closing cairo-dock and starting it up again, but at every system start up I have the same problem!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43867401/Schermata%20del%202014-02-06%2012%3A43%3A30.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 14.04 Cairo-Dock. On start up the dock would align to the right of the screen and half the apps could not be seen. To bring it back into alignment I have to right click on the dock, go to Cairo-Dock, configure and before the configuration window popped up the dock would realign itself. Then had to close the configuration window. Had to do that every time I rebooted. I tried to uninstall and re install the Cairo-Dock through the command line, but that did not work.

I right clicked on the Cairo-Dock, up to Cairo-Dock, configure, then wait for the configuration window opens. Go to themes tab to your right. Click on the theme you have chosen and have been using. Go to apply down the bottom right. Now you will have a choice, green tick, continue and loose any changes you have made or red cross to cancel. I was just able to press the cancel button and my dock repaired itself and has opened correctly ever since. You may need to apply the changes if that doesn't work. You will have to adjust all your apps, but it worked for me.

I am a new user myself, so let me know how you went.